# In Gitlab, file hook gets executed by user "gitlab" but doesn't exist

Tags: gitlab

I have my own GitLab server and try to execute a file hook at a certain event. With a Python script I found out, that the event hook gets executed by a user called `gitlab`, but the Ubuntu system does not have a registered user with that name.

```
$ groups gitlab
groups: ‘gitlab’: no such user
```

Does anyone know how I can get more information about this "virtual" user?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my own solution. Although Python returns `gitlab` the user seems to be just called `git`.

```
$ groups git
git : git
```